# This search function seems to break on the third call to it, no mater what I do?

Tags: vba, excel

In my code I have a little error coding just before calling the function that this code resides in. I thought there was something in the 'Dur section that was breaking the function because when the last `gFindInColumn(sStr, Range("C3:C" & lRow))` is called I can step through the function ok and it even gets the data I want but rather than returning and placing the data in `sRow(2,2)` it returns to my error coding section.

Note: that I commented out the entire Dur section so `sStr` contains the same exact data as in 'Pre which makes it through `gFindInColumn`

```
    'Pre
dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.Show
temp = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaseLineEndTemp.Value
sStr = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaselineStartDate.Value & " " & dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaselineStartTime.Value
eStr = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaselineEndDate.Value & " " & dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBPreBaselineEndTime.Value
lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
sRow(1, 1) = gFindInColumn(sStr, Range("C3:C" & lRow))
eRow(1, 1) = gFindInColumn(eStr, Range("C3:C" & lRow))
'Call addFormulaTestDataLoop(temp, sRow(1, 1), eRow(1, 1))

'Dur
'temp = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaseLineEndTemp.Value
'sStr = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaselineStartDate.Value & " " & dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaselineStartTime.Value
'eStr = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaselineEndtDate.Value & " " & dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtBDurBaselineEndTime.Value
'qtyDur = dlgSysteEPatchTempDateTime.txtDurQty.Value

'wsData.Activate
sRow(2, 2) = gFindInColumn(sStr, Range("C3:C" & lRow))
```

and

```
 Public Function gFindInColumn(search As Variant, rngCol As Range, Optional rowNum As Long = 2) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = rngCol.Find(What:=search, After:=rngCol.Cells(rowNum), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'only return non-zero if the found cell is *after* rowNum
        gFindInColumn = IIf(f.row > rowNum, f.row, 0)
    Else
        gFindInColumn = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the `On Error Goto` statement to see what's actually going on?

Comment: @Mistella- I don't see an `on error goto` statement

Comment: No, good idea...didn't even cross my mind

Comment: You could enhance readability in `gFindInColumn` by inverting the condition of your `If` statement: `If f Is Nothing Then : gFindInColumn = 0 : Else ...`. Gets you to the same place, easier on the eyes.

Comment: @Davesexcel. Even I was baffled by that statement but then realized what was going on :D Mistella deduced that from OPs statement `..it returns to my error coding section...`

Comment: Ricky, Did you manage to get an error message?

Comment: is `sRow(2,2)` a valid, existing array entry? Is the bit where you've activated `wsData.Activate` then changing the range you pass to `gFindInColumn` ?

Comment: No error message, it goes to end function and rather than returning to sRow(2, 2) it returns to the end of ErrTitle: which is at the end of all my code. I'll comment that all out too. maybe that will help

Comment: finally got script out of range, it has to do with how I declared the array

Comment: @jamheadart it was the array element Declared it Public sRow(1,1) As Integer
Public eRow(1,1) As Integer LOL Thanks guys for pulling my head our of you know where

Comment: Ah, good deduction @Mistella

Comment: @Davesexcel Thanks. :) I'm glad it helped solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @Mistella Thanks for the help, would have  been banging my head against the keyboard for a few more hours without it!! ;-) Davesexcel too ;-)